# При клике на input внутри <td> с listener'ом функция вызывается дважды

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-events

Всем привет!

Мне нужна помощь со следующей ситуацией. В разметке html есть следующий блок:

```
<td class="statistics-section__body-cell statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox flex">
    <label class="statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox-input-label">
        <input class="statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox-input" type="checkbox">
    </label>
</td>
```

И на *td*, а точнее, на его класс, навешан прослушиватель:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox").forEach(function(newBreakPointWindow) {
  newBreakPointWindow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let parent = e.currentTarget;
    (и остальная функция)
    ...
  })
});
```

Label у меня стилизован под input, а сам input скрыт:

```
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
height: 0;
```

Задумка в том, что сама ячейка td имеет определённые размеры, а input - это всего лишь небольшой чекбокс, и дабы не целиться каждый раз в этот чекбокс, можно было бы просто кликнуть на ячейку с ним и активировать привязанную функцию.
Когда я кликаю на td, всё работает хорошо.
Проблема начинается, когда клик происходит непосредственно по "чекбоксу". По какой-то причине функция, привязанная к прослушивателю, вызывается дважды.
Это при том, что сам инпут скрыт css-свойствами. А даже если бы и не был скрыт, такое поведение мне всё равно непонятно.

Пробовал даже экспериментировать и заменял input на пустой div. В результате двойной вызов функции не происходит.
Возможно, кто-то сможет подсказать, что это за магия input'а такая, и как можно без загромождения кода в скрипте предотвратить двойной вызов по нажатию на чекбокс?

Comment: Очень похоже на всплытие/погружение. Случайно, на сам чекбокс ещё одна прослушка нигде не завалялась?

Comment: Полагаю, это происходит из-за вложенности `input` в `label`. При клике непосредственно на "чекбокс" вызывается и клик на `input`. Ну а далее происходит то самое всплытие, о котором упомянули в комментарии выше.
P.S. Такая же ситуация будет, если вы вдруг решите использовать `<label for="id_input"`. Предлагаю отследить `event.target` и проверить, является ли он "input'ом". Если да - `return false`

Comment: @vegasmoscow да, listener есть и на инпуте, и на label'е.
Но опять же, если ради эксперимента подложить в label вместо инпута div, то эта проблема не возникает.
Насколько я понимаю, addEventListener добавляет прослушивание и на все дочерние элементы.

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st попробовал
    let parent = e.currentTarget;
    if (e.target !== parent) return false;
но в результате функция просто перестала выполняться на моменте return false. 
При этом, запуск функции всё также происходит 2 раза.

Comment: _addEventListener добавляет прослушивание и на все дочерние элементы_ - нет, не добавляет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.currentTarget - Всегда совпадает с элементом, на котором обработчик события был назначен

e.target - Совпадает с элементом, на котором событие возникло.

Что происходит у вас в коде при выполнении кода:

```
let parent = e.currentTarget; if (e.target !== parent) return false;
```

При клике на ячейку у вас `e.currentTarget` === ячейка, и `e.target` === ячейка
Ваша запись вернет false и ничего не сработает

При клике на чекбокс будет клик на чекбоксе и на ячейке,
при этом всплытие никто не отменял, следовательно:

`e.currentTarget` === чекбоксу, `e.target` === чекбоксу, снова вернется false,

Далее будет всплытие события:

`e.currentTarget` === ячейка, `e.target` === чекбокс, и вот тут ваше условие срабатывает и вернется true

Т.е. Ваш код работает лишь при прямом нажатии на чекбокс.

Есть более элегантное решение:
Замените
`document.querySelectorAll(".statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox")` на `document.querySelectorAll("td.statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox")`

Таким образом ваш обработчик события будет назначаться лишь на ячейку таблицы, а не на вложенные элементы.

- Советую при скрытии элемента задавать ему отрицательный z-index

Comment: К сожалению, вариант с document.querySelectorAll("td.statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox") почему-то не помог. По-прежнему вижу, что на всех дочерних элементах, label и input, висит прослушиватель click.  

Отрицательный z-index также не возымел эффекта.
К слову, когда-то слышал рекомендацию, что z-index не стоит делать отрицательным из соображений производительности css. Но наверно, главное, вы исходили из того, чтобы его положение было ниже всех остальных, кого он может перекрывать.

Comment: UPD:
Заметил, что при клике на чекбокс (и по совместительству, label), двойной вызов происходит сначала по target = label, а потом по target = input.  
Если же повторять мой эксперимент с заменой label на div, то в этом случае вызывается только target = div. Инпут внутри него не дёргается, как это происходит, находясь он в label.

Comment: Альтернативный вариант - отмените всплытие собтий добавив в функцию первой строчкой "event.stopPropagation()" - это предотвратит всплытие и клик будет происходить лишь на том элементе, на котором вы кликнули.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас закрался еще один слушатель событий на лейбле с чекбоксом, про который вы забыли. Попробуйте поискать другие обработчики событий, кроме текущего

Comment: Нет, кроме этого, больше там нет слушателей, проверял уже неоднократно.
Но тем не менее, спасибо за помощь, теперь у меня получилось более осознанно разобраться с тем, как работают target и currentTarget, поэтому у меня получилось решить свою проблему своего рода костылём:
`{
    let parent = e.currentTarget;
    let doubleCallFix = document.querySelectorAll(".statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox-input")[0];
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
      if (e.target !== doubleCallFix) {
        return false;
  };
};`

Comment: Единственное, что осталось мною не понято:
1. Это почему при клике на label (в роли target'а) вызывается также и input в роли target'а, в то время, как если вместо label'а какой-нибудь div или span, то в роли target'а вызывается только он. Чего мне и хотелось бы от label'а.  
2. Почему не сработало `document.querySelectorAll("td.statistics-section__body-cell-breakpoint-checkbox")`, и слушатель навешался на дочерние элементы.  

Но это нужно уже копать дальше, видимо. Во всяком случае, основная проблема решена, спасибо!

Comment: @Lotrein 1) Это происходит по причине того, что `label` обладает на уровне спецификации особенностью - при клике на `label` произойдёт клик и на вложенный (читаем "связанный с  данным `label'ом`") элемент. Как если бы мы просто кликнули по `input`. Это произойдёт и в случае использования `for` у `label` (читаем "связывание `label` с элементом через атрибут `for`"). Об этом можно в спецификации к html-элементу `label` почитать (извиняюсь, что в первом комментарии не смог более подробно объяснить).

Comment: 2) Насколько я знаю, указание непосредственно тега в качестве selector'а или любое другое более точное указание selector'а не остановит поведение всплытия/погружения. Иначе говоря, если мы совершим клик по элементу, то по умолчанию он будет подниматься вверх до самого "верхнего" родителя, пока не дойдёт до `document` (вроде он последний на всплытии в цепочке DOM. Скажем "входной элемент" в DOM). То есть если мы кликнем на `label`, то событие сработает и на нём, и на `td`, ну и на связанном `input'е` тоже. Такие вот дела.

Comment: Да, всплытие не остановит, но должно убрать обработчик события с вложенных элементов с таким же классом.  И заставить скрипт работать лишь на элементе таблицы. Логика была в этом

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях вам уже написали, что label, при клике на нём, согласно спецификации, вызовет клик и на вложенном input. Такое у него поведение по умолчанию. Это как при клике на ссылку с пустым href происходит перезагрузка страницы. Или при клике на кнопку submit формы происходит также перезагрузка страницы.

В вашем случае решить данную проблему легко - вешайте обработчик события не на label, а на сам чекбокс. И тогда, даже по клику на label, автоматически произойдет клик и на чекбоксе (даже если он скрыт).

Запустите мой код ниже и увидите, что сам чекбокс скрыт, но событие на нём срабатвает.

```js
// Селектором ищем не label, а сам checkbox
document.querySelector(".checkbox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
    console.log('Сработал клик по чекбоксу');
    // (и остальная функция)
      
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.table-cell {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: plum;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.label {
    display:flex; /* без этого label станет невидимым */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #666666;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
    <table>
        <td class="table-cell">
            <label class="label">Label
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
            </label>

        </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: Проверил ваш вариант, понял, как он работает.
Но к моему случаю он не совсем подходит, так как мой label - это стилизация под чекбокс, с небольшим размером. Поэтому мне в любом случае нужно организовывать клик на ячейку, чтобы не целиться в чекбокс.

Но пока я проверял этот вариант, пришло осознание, что label уже не столь актуален для меня, т.к. атрибут checked проще поставить через JS, а label заменить на span.
Сейчас проверил, вроде очень даже рабочий вариант.  
  
`<td>
       <span class="label">Label
           <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
       </span>
</td>`

Comment: @Lotrein, всё верно. Вешайте прослушку на td и далее уже управляйте input-ом. Label  в данном случае со своим избыточным поведением не нужен.